# Яндекс.карты список регионов

Tags: яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Как получить список всех регионов России с их координатами (+ другие страны с их координатами), чтобы можно было вывести их в выпадающем списке и по нажатию на объект карта перемещалась к этому месту по координатам? Вытащил с левого сайта json с подобными объектами:

```json
{
      "id": 122,
      "name": "Алжир",
      "pointsCount": 1,
      "center": {
        "lat": 36.769573,
        "lng": 3.031128
      },
      "bounds": [
        [
          36.769573,
          3.031128
        ],
        [
          36.769573,
          3.031128
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Алтайский край",
      "pointsCount": 135,
      "center": {
        "lat": 53.375676,
        "lng": 62.10617
      },
      "bounds": [
        [
          51.000351,
          37.616667
        ],
        [
          55.751,
          86.595673
        ]
      ]
    },
```

Там в перемешку регионы РФ + страны, подскажите, откуда такое можно получить или сгенерировать? Там даже написано количество точек, которое есть в этом регионе.. В API яндекс карт не нашёл.